# Bucketing numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, weighting

I have a list of numbers e.g 1-to 60, but not necessarily in increments of 1.  E.g 1-40 in increments of 1, and 40-60 in increments of two.

I have another set of defined numbers  (buckets) –e.g 2,  3,  5 , 10, 30, 50

I need to produce a two dimensional array with percentages of where each number from above (1 to 60) fits into which bucket.

to make this simpler: let’s say we have numbers 1 to 10, and buckets, 2, 3, 5,  10

I want my two dimensional array to look like this:

[image]

I can do this with a bunch of conditionals, but I think there’s a solution out there which I have not thought of and would be great if someone could shed some light!
I need to do this in JavaScript, but any language would help me to try and  understand any solution more optimal than lots of if’s deciding where each number fits and then doing  (6-5/10-5)=0.2 for each cell.

I’m trying to avoid hardcoding buckets, 2, 3, 5, 10 so that any set of buckets or numbers can do the job.

**EDIT:**
First of all, I'm sorry for the incomplete description - I was on my phone at the time and couldn't post on stackoverflow via a computer.

Both 1-10 and 2,3,5,10 represent years. Effectively, I'm trying to bucket each year from 1 to 10.

- Year 1 goes 100% into Bucket 2 - I guess there isn't a specific
  formula for this cell
- Year 2 goes 100% into Bucket 2 - No specific formula either
- Year 3 goes 100% into Bucket 3 - 3==3
- Year 4 is split half between Bucket 3, and half between Bucket 5. The formula for this is: (Year 4 - Bucket 3)/(Bucket 5 - Bucket 3) = 0.5

  - Year 5 goes 100% into Bucket 5.
  - Year 6, goes 80% into Bucket 5, and 20% into Bucket 10. The formula for this is: 1-(6-5)/(10-5)=0.8 and for its neighbouring cell (6-5)/(10-5)
  - ...and so on...

I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Could you explain the relation between the inputs/ouputs? Why are [3,4] and [5,4] both `0.5`?

Comment: Yes sure - (4-3)/(5-3), that's for [5,4] and it's neighbour is just 1-that.

Comment: You mean (5+4)=(10-3*(1/3)) ?

Comment: And how is that abstracted to the position of [0,0], [3,9], [10,9]? What steps need to be taken with the 'x' numerals and 'y' numerals to find the result at the [x,y] coordinates? You need to clearly explain the problem you're trying to solve because, as it is, we (or at least **I**) have no idea how to help you.

Comment: For (3,9): 1-(9-5)/(10-5) and (10,9) is (9-5)/(10-5). Unfortunately I'm having to type all of this on my phone which is not very easy, so I'm sorry if I wasn't very clear. Effectively 2,3,5 10 represent bucketed years and I want to work out how much percentage should go into each of those buckets  based on years 1 to 10. Hope this helps

Comment: @kkudi : What do you want most ? 1) make people loose their time 2) Propose an enigma or 3) get an answer ? 
If 1) or 2), change nothing. I you want an answer, get a keyboard and make the question clear.

Comment: I'm genuinely sorry, because this seems a potentially interesting question, but you're neglecting to explain how the output is produced (you've shown some working, but not explained that working; which serves to complicate the question rather than clarify it). Until, or unless you can, clarify and explain I'm voting to place your question on hold as 'unclear what you're asking.'

Comment: @DavidThomas I have edited the question to hopefully be clearer. I guess I'm struggling myself to find a formula that will cater for all edge cases to bucket a list of years into weights, which is why I came here for help.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Hopefully 3). I have now got a hold of a keyboard and I tried to make the question clearer. IF you still think it's unclear please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. It puts it in exactly the format you asked for in the post:

```
function bucketize(numberList, buckets) {
    // buckets must contain values sorted from smallest to largest
    var bucketized = [];
    var i, j, lowBucket, difference, bucketSpan, ratio;

    for (i=0; i<numberList.length; i++) {
        bucketized[i]=new Array(buckets.length + 1);
        bucketized[i][0]=numberList[i];
        lowBucketIndex=null;

        for (j=0; j<buckets.length; j++) {
            if (lowBucketIndex === null && numberList[i] < buckets[j]) {
                lowBucketIndex=j-1;
                if (lowBucketIndex < 0) {
                    // this bucket gets it all
                    bucketized[i][j+1]=1;
                } else {
                    //divide this value between buckets
                    difference = numberList[i] - buckets[lowBucketIndex];
                    bucketSpan = buckets[j] - buckets[lowBucketIndex];
                    ratio=difference/bucketSpan;
                    bucketized[i][lowBucketIndex+1] = 1-ratio;
                    bucketized[i][j+1] = ratio;
                }
            } else {
                bucketized[i][j+1]=0;
            }
        }
        if (lowBucketIndex === null) {
            bucketized[i][buckets.length] = 1;
        }
    }

    return bucketized;
}

var buckets = [2,3,5,10];
var numberList=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var bucketized = bucketize(numberList, buckets);
var i;

for (i=0; i<bucketized.length; i++) {
    console.log(bucketized[i].join(','));
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pocq61gq/7/).